# Resources for Learning Spanish

Tags: soporte, faq, ámbito, formulado-de-preguntas, motivos-de-cierre

> <sup>Meta is for questions about *"the workings and policies of Spanish Language Stack Exchange"* (source: [What's Meta?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)). This question was outside of said scope, so it's been repurposed as a FAQ on the topic.</sup>

From time to time, a (new) user comes to the Spanish.SE asking for resources to further improve their Spanish.
Some other times, a user finds a new useful site (or even create one themselves!) and wants to share it with the community, but doesn't know how.

- What is the stance of Spanish.SE on questions regarding learning resources?
- What should I expect if I post a question asking for learning resources?
- Is it OK for me to post an auto-answered question to share a cool new dictionary / translator / some other Spanish learning resource I found or created? How about answering questions by linking to said resource?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73772/discussion-on-question-by-fedorqui-resources-for-learning-spanish). Also, answers have been deleted, since all of them are now in the main site.

Comment: The location at the main site: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23617/9385

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- ***What's the stance of Spanish.SE on questions regarding learning resources?***

> The Spanish.SE community maintains a **canonical CW question, with categorized CW answers, containing a ton of resources** that may be useful while learning Spanish:
>
> #### → **[Resources for learning Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23617/1674)** ←
>
> Please feel free to improve the answers to that question with any resources you know!

- ***Why having a question like this on the main site instead of Meta? Isn't that against the general "no questions asking for lists of X" policy?***

> Spanish.SE is a stack for expert Spanish linguists, but also for Spanish learners.
>
> Having such a question on the main site was deemed more productive and welcoming to learning users than just closing their questions as off-topic and having them  coming to Meta to ask non-Meta questions about learning resources :)
>   For more info on this decision, see [this Meta question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2740/proposal-move-resources-for-learning-question-to-the-main-site).

- ***So... are new questions about learning resources allowed in the main site?***

> Yes. But you have to make sure that the resource you are looking for isn't already listed in the main *Resources* question linked above, and explain why none of those fit your need. **If you don't justify posting a new "resources" question, it will probably be closed as a duplicate** of the main one.
>
> If you still think you should post a new question, be sure to tag it as [resources](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources).

- ***I posted a new question asking for a specific resource. Now what?***

> Now wait for answers :)
>
> Once your question has been answered, and after a reasonable amount of time has passed (so you get some rep for your contribution!), any new resources might be included in one of the categories, and your question might be closed as a duplicate anyways -- so people know those resources are now included in the main *Resources* question too.
>
> If your question is not getting any answers, maybe the resource you're looking for is too *niche*, or maybe the question didn't get enough visibility. As with any other question, you can use bounties, share links etc. to solve that :)

- ***There's this new great site that I made / a new resource that I found. How can I share it with Spanish.SE's community?***

> If you know of an online resource that would be useful for the users of Spanish.SE and it is not listed in any of the answers to the main *Resources* question, please **don't make a new question just for that. Instead, edit one of the existing answers and include the resource in there** for everybody to see!
>
> If you don't have enough reputation to edit CW answers yet, please have a look around and contribute some new useful answers and questions to get that rep bump we all love :)
>   You can even use that new resource in your answers, as long as you follow the [How To Answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) guidelines ;)
>
> Make yourself at home!