# aprendizaje tag wiki: encourage people to submit questions to Language Learning SE?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

The tag wiki excerpt for [aprendizaje](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aprendizaje) (to which [learning](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) redirects) currently says,

> Do not use this tag: questions related to learning the Spanish language (tips, learning materials and so on) are off-topic and will almost certainly be closed.

The tag wiki contains a link to [*Resources* for learning Spanish](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2514/1674), but does not tell people where to go with learning-related questions that have nothing to do with resources. Are there any objections against adding something along the following lines?

> For questions about learning Spanish that have nothing to do with resources, you can go to [Language Learning Stack Exchange](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/).

["Disclaimer": I am the most active user on Language Learning Stack Exchange.]

**Update**: since the tags [aprendizaje](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aprendizaje) and [learning](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) were [removed in early 2018](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2869/13852), this question is overtake by events.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from [its revisions page](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/10108/revisions), the content you quote is quite new. The last question that used [aprendizaje](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aprendizaje) was asked more than 6 months ago, so it has not been of much use.

This being said, I think yours is a very good idea, so I just added the content you suggested.

Feel free to add more info to our canonical [Resources for learning Spanish](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2514/1674) or to suggest changes in the tag description!