# Let's retire a tag whose instructions say "do not use this tag"!

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas

It is [aprendizaje](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aprendizaje)  The definition starts out, "Do not use this tag."

Let's not leave little land mines like this lying around for people to step on by accident.

There is a synonym [learning](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) which also says "Do not use this tag."

Obviously if this proposal succeeds, we'll need to retag any questions that have "aprendizaje" as their sole tag.  I'm happy to help with this.  I will wait for discussion and a decision, though.

Comment: I agree. We don't have many questions here, [`[aprendizaje] closed:no`](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Baprendizaje%5D+closed%3Ano) returns just 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For tracking purposes, let's list all the questions that contain the [aprendizaje](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aprendizaje) tag.

These are open:

- <s>[How can I order food in Spanish, without the waiter switching to English?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16363/how-can-i-order-food-in-spanish-without-the-waiter-switching-to-english)</s> retagged
- <s>[¿Existe alguna clasificación de palabras para determinar si son positivas o negativas?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/9816/an%c3%a1lisis-sentimental)</s> retagged
- <s>[Does the Spanish Wikipedia use correct Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5511/can-i-trust-the-spanish-wikipedia)</s> - closed & retagged
- <s>[Watch TV Show with English or lower quality Spanish Subtitles](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3849/watch-tv-show-with-english-or-lower-quality-spanish-subtitles)</s> retagged
- <s>[Participating in a Spanish proficiency test?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3715/participating-in-a-spanish-proficiency-test)</s> - closed now & retagged
- <s>[Early childhood Spanish language immersion accent exposure](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3340/early-childhood-spanish-language-immersion-accent-exposure)</s> closed & retagged

These are closed:

- <s>https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16362/relearning-spanish-for-a-vacation-in-spain</s> deleted
- <s>[Native-speaking Spanish radio station or podcast for learning?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15356/native-speaking-spanish-radio-station-or-podcast-for-learning)</s> retagged
- <s>https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12192/where-to-begin-to-learn-spanish</s> deleted
- <s>[Download Spanish–English translations (esp. conjugations) as Open Data](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8360/download-spanish-english-translations-esp-conjugations-as-open-data)</s> retagged
- <s>https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8350/how-to-find-video-games-with-heavy-spanish-language-incorporation</s> roomba killed it
- <s>https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3492/easy-reading-for-someone-with-one-year-in-spanish-language</s> deleted
- <s>[How can I learn basic vocabulary?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3221/learn-basic-vocabulary)</s> retagged
- <s>[Good *extensible* dictionary software?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2057/good-extensible-dictionary-software)</s> retagged
- <s>[Continuing education after high school](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1820/continuing-education-after-high-school)</s> retagged
- <s>https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1812/good-news-chat-cultural-podcasts-in-spanish</s> deleted (6 years, 500 views)
- <s>https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/570/what-is-a-good-original-spanish-childrens-novel-to-help-learn-grammar-and-vocab</s> roomba killed it
- <s>[American style TV shows in Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/272/american-style-tv-shows-in-spanish)</s> retagged

Comment: Fedorqui, you've been a busy bee!  Thank you for all that housekeeping work. // I noticed that the first question on the list was a problem because it only had the one tag, *aprendizaje*.  I have added *comida* tentatively, and have proposed a new tag, *bilingualism*.  We can make a Meta question to discuss the new tag proposal if you like.  I will wait to look for more questions that might be candidates for such a tag. My reasoning in wanting to tag it *bilingualism*: I think the problem described by OP is down to the waiters (and OP) being bilingual. If you prefer we could make ...

Comment: ... a *codeswitching* tag instead.  That word is quite in vogue these days, and its existence might trigger a bunch of interesting questions. Or, we could make "codeswitching" and "bilingualism" synonyms of each other.

Comment: @aparente001 mmm that may be a good idea! I added it to the other one question that was missing to cross out from the list, so now we are done with retagging and [tag:aprendizaje] is not in use anymore :)

Comment: Thanks.  I added the tag to some other questions -- I searched for "switch."  I have some other search ideas but that should be for another day, so as not to overwhelm the recent activity roll.

Comment: @aparente001 I made [tag:codeswitching] synonym of [tag:bilingüismo] as well, as discussed here one month ago.

Comment: Thanks.  I suppose *codeswitching* is a more specific subset of *bilingualism*.  I would be happy with just having *bilingualism/bilingüismo* and scrapping my earlier *codeswitching* idea.  But I'm okay with whatever you decide about that.

Comment: @aparente001 let's handle this from down to top: see how we should tag some types of questions and consistenly use the tags. I started yesterday with [¿Cómo deberíamos etiquetar las preguntas en las que se observa laísmo, leísmo o loísmo?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2924/1674)

Comment: I've got some time-sensitive things to do just now but later could we have a chat about this please?  "Top down" could mean a variety of things and I want to make sure I understand how you want me to do things.  I'm doing my best to follow the directions I was given not to clutter up Meta. // "Leísmo" is one of the thornier tag housekeeping issues; there are some that I think are straightforward and I would like to make sure I'm explaining clearly what I mean by my request that all tags be available (with appropriate synonym connections established) in both languages, to maximize access to...

Comment: the site by Spanish learners, which I hope will increase traffic to the site and help us in our goal to graduate from Beta.  Since my previous comment about bilingual tag synonyms wasn't clear, I think it would help if we could coordinate our schedules to take a few minutes to have a live chat where I can clarify what I was trying to convey when talking about dual synonym pairs (e.g. "direct-object"/"objeto-directo").

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread "down to top."  (I think the opposite of "top-down" is usually "bottom-up" because the mistake I made is pretty common.)  At any rate, I'm still not certain what you meant by "down to top," so hopefully we can talk about this at some point over the next few days.

Answer (score 3):

I seem to remember writing at some point that the only use case that I could find to keep a tag that said "do not use this tag" is if we see that this tags gets periodically created, misused and deleted, over and over again. The rationale would be "better to keep the tag and document the problem on it's wiki info than hitting and discussing the problem in meta all over again".

I don't think that this is the case, so I'll vote (officially) to delete them.

I think that we already discussed [repurposing the “aprendizaje” tag](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2802/5481). I don't think that this tag can be salvaged, so it should be deleted.

When I see the tag aprendizaje, I think it should be related to questions related to "how to learn" and seeing [fedorqui's post](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2870/5481) most of these questions tend to be closed of could probably use some other tag about what you are trying to learn about, so I don't see the point of that tag.