# ¿Cómo deberíamos etiquetar las preguntas sobre pronombres 'la', 'le' y 'lo' y en las que se observa laísmo, leísmo o loísmo?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Estaba intentando mejorar la pregunta [Dado "... existe un tipo de sordera (...). Se *le* conoce como X", ¿podríamos decir "se *lo* conoce"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/25999/1674), que versa sobre el pronombre personal átono *la*, *le* y *lo*. Es un tema común y complicado para los que aprenden la lengua (incluso los nativos nos equivocamos a veces *usándolosleslos* ;D) y se junta con el mal común del laísmo, leísmo y loísmo, como bien apunta la [respuesta de pablodf76](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26018/1674).

Se trata, pues, de un caso en el que claramente parece pertinente etiquetar con:

- [pronombres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronombres)
- [gramática](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gram%c3%a1tica) - <sub>una etiqueta cuyo sobresuso (700 de 5000 preguntas la llevan) me hace pensar que es demasiado genérica.</sub>

Pero luego... observo que tenemos [laísmo-leísmo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/la%c3%adsmo-le%c3%adsmo) con preguntas como:

- [Is «le imitó» an example of «leísmo» and is it only considered correct usage in Spain?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23792/1674)
- [Le estamos atendiendo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3884/1674)
- Y luego la canónica, que es [What are leísmo, loísmo, and laísmo?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/670/1674)

Y además también tenemos [lo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lo), que parece demasiado específica y algo coja porque no tiene sus equivalentes [la](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/la) ni [le](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/le). Eso sí, resulta útil al ser usada en preguntas como ['Lo bastante/suficientemente + adjetivo + como para' - Is it possible to drop 'lo' and 'como para'?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21643/1674).

Observo pues una cierta jerarquía incompleta en las etiquetas, comenzando por la base más genérica que es [gramática](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gram%c3%a1tica), seguida por [pronombres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronombres) y después una cierta dispersión entre [objeto-directo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objeto-directo), [objeto-indirecto](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objeto-indirecto) (o la recién creada [objetos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objetos)).

**¿Cómo deberíamos etiquetar estas preguntas? Definamos claramente sus *excerpt* y *wiki* para que quede claro para los futuros usuarios. Después, una vez decidido, reetiquetemos.**

<sub>Comienzo aquí una serie de preguntas para intentar clarificar el uso de las etiquetas. Actualmente observo cierto descontrol que nos lleva a tener preguntas duplicadas una de la otra con una intersección de etiquetas casi vacía.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo de etiquetar jerárquicamente tiene un problema de profundidad.
Dentro de los `pronombres` tenemos los `personales` y los `no personales`; dentro de los `personales`, están los `tónicos`, los `clíticos` y los `posesivos` (y los `reflexivos` y los `recíprocos` como subgrupo de los `clíticos`); dentro de los `no personales` tenemos los `demostrativos`, los `indefinidos`, los `interrogativos`...

Si etiquetamos jerárquicamente, una pregunta sobre el uso de "se" debería llevar las etiquetas [gramática](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gram%c3%a1tica) [pronombres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronombres) [pronombres-personales](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronombres-personales) [clíticos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cl%c3%adticos), y luego [reflexivos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reflexivos) o [recíprocos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rec%c3%adprocos) según aplique. O quizá ambos, si la duda es sobre eso.

Pero una pregunta admite como máximo solo 5 etiquetas. Con lo anterior ya nos hemos comido 4 o 5, y no dejamos sitio para otras etiquetas que puedan referirse a otros aspectos de la pregunta (`objeto-indirecto`, `historia`, `traducción`, etc.) así que ¿dónde paramos?

Si queremos mantener la jerarquía, una opción podría ser, para las subdivisiones menores, incluir la jerarquía en la propia etiqueta: tener [pronombres-personales](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronombres-personales), [pronombres-personales-clíticos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronombres-personales-cl%c3%adticos) y [pronombres-personales-clíticos-reflexivos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronombres-personales-cl%c3%adticos-reflexivos), y así sólo tenemos que usar el último de ellos.
La otra opción sería saltar directamente de [pronombres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronombres) a [reflexivos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reflexivos) y ya está, que es más o menos lo que estamos haciendo ahora, pero entonces no se puede decir que sea una clasificación jerárquica *stricto sensu* (o, más bien, no será una jerarquía completa).

Por otro lado, el problema que le veo a centrarnos en hacer este tipo de etiquetas es que puede haber gente que no sepa si una palabra es un pronombre, o un objeto indirecto, o qué. Entonces, a la hora de etiquetar, no van a saber por dónde tirar.
Para estas personas que aún están aprendiendo la terminología gramatical, resultaría más sencillo disponer de sinónimos como [la-le-lo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/la-le-lo) que describan claramente el tema de la pregunta desde su punto de vista.

Asunto aparte es el tema de [laísmo-leísmo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/la%c3%adsmo-le%c3%adsmo). Este tag se refiere a un fenómeno bien identificado y no creo que deba usarse para cualquier pregunta que verse sobre el uso de `la` o `le`.

Entonces, y por responder algo concreto, **propuesta para etiquetar preguntas sobre el uso de `la`, `le`, `lo`**:

- Etiqueta general [gramática](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gram%c3%a1tica).
- Etiqueta general [pronombres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronombres) (o directamente [pronombres-personales](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronombres-personales)).
- Etiqueta específica [clíticos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cl%c3%adticos).

  - Etiqueta sinónima [la-le-lo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/la-le-lo) para facilitar el etiquetado a los usuarios menos avanzados.
- Reservar la etiqueta [laísmo-leísmo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/la%c3%adsmo-le%c3%adsmo) solo para preguntas específicas sobre esos fenómeno. Tampoco estaría de más renombrarla a [laísmo-leísmo-loísmo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/la%c3%adsmo-le%c3%adsmo-lo%c3%adsmo) para incluir también el muy relacionado *loísmo*, tal como apuntas.

Posiblemente no haya tenido en cuenta algún caso o alguna división, si veis algo que deba añadir comentadlo.

Comment: Me gusta la recomendación final que haces y creo que podríamos ir en esta dirección. La gracia de cómo lo tenemos ahora es que incluso tenemos la etiqueta [tag:se]... :O O sea que tu idea podría ser una buena manera de avanzar en la buena dirección y dejarlo bien clasificado por unos años.

Comment: Gran respuesta, gracias por ella. Opino que los nodos superiores de la jerarquía se pueden omitir, gramática especialmente. Luego utilizar [tag:pronombres] seguido de [tag:pronombres-personales] (incluso omitiendo el primero), seguido por algo tipo [tag:clíticos] me parece buena idea. La clave aquí es que sean etiquetas lo suficientemente grandes como para que sirvan para clasificar (y no aislar), pero no tanto como para que no sirvan para nada.

Comment: _Entonces, a la hora de etiquetar, no van a saber por dónde tirar_, bueno este es un problema común a todos los Stacks. La gente menos acostumbrada etiqueta como buenamente puede, luego los más veteranos le ponen las etiquetas más precisas.

Comment: En cuanto a [tag:laísmo-leísmo], ¿te parece englobar también el _loísmo_ y tener [tag:laísmo-leísmo-loísmo]?

Comment: Claro, la cuestión es dejarlo reposar unos días y ver qué más se comenta. En una semana lo revisamos.

Comment: Respuesta aceptada e implementada. Tenemos a partir de ya [tag:clíticos] con [unos cuantos sinónimos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/cl%C3%ADticos/synonyms): pronombre-la, pronombre-le, pronombre-lo, la-le-lo, lo y le. También he renombrado laísmo-leísmo a [tag:laísmo-leísmo-loísmo]. He reetiquetado las preguntas utilizando gramática-pronombres-clíticos. No he añadido [tag:pronombres-personales] porque no había espacio.

Comment: Veo que me he confundido un poco y no siempre debería usar [tag:clíticos] para preguntas sobre pronomes personales. Queda pendiente añadir [tag:pronombres-personales] en aquellas donde [tag:clíticos] no aplique.

Comment: Me he liado. Sí estaba bien el uso de _clíticos_ para los pronombres personales átonos (DPD http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=elLl31yYnD65MTS9uF). De todos modos, revisemos entre todos que esté todo bien etiquetado. ¡Gracias por todo!