# Vota pronto y con frecuencia

Tags: discusión, faq, votos

> Esta es una traducción libre de [Vote Early, Vote Often](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/19/vote-early-vote-often/).

¿Te has preguntado alguna vez por qué los botones para votar aparecen tan prominentemente en cada pregunta de [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites)?

[image]

Situar la votación de una forma central es muy intencional; así es como...

- el contenido bueno sube y se consigue destacar
- el contenido malo o incorrecto va para abajo
- los usuarios que consistentemente ofrecen contenido útil acumulan reputación y [se les conceden más privilegios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) en el sitio

Es solamente con el voto que puede emerger un grupo de editores, personas que votan para cerrar preguntas, y moderadores. El liderazgo del sitio se forma a través del voto. Es por eso que las [ligas de reputación](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/163/alltime/spanish/) muestran un desglose de las franjas de reputación.

[image]

¿Tiene tu sitio un grupo sano de usuarios medios que pueden votar positiva y negativamente, así como editar etiquetas? ¿Tiene también un grupo de usuarios gobernantes con privilegios para editar, cerrar y [moderar](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)? Todo esto requiere un nivel suficiente de reputación, que a su vez requiere de usuarios que ejerciten su derecho a voto.

Es por ello que en [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) se muestra una métrica de cuántos usuarios *ávidos* hay, donde *ávidos* se refiere a tener al menos 200 puntos de reputación.

[image]

(estas son las [estadísticas de Spanish Language](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language) como sitio Beta, por ejemplo.)

Todos nuestros sitios están pensados para ser un tipo de democracia representativa. Si bien la [elecciones anuales a moderador](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/02/09/stack-overflow-2010-moderator-election-results/) son una parte importante del sistema, votar preguntas y las respuestas es el mecanismo fundamental a través del cual la comunidad gobierna el sitio en el día a día.

Votar es *tan* importante que nos dimos cuenta de que hay que transmitirlo de forma clara a los nuevos usuarios y así animarlos a que voten. Por ello:

- Al punto que un usuario puede empezar a votar, recibe una [notificación](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/07/membership-has-its-privileges/) en la que se lo explica.
- Existen unas cuantas [medallas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/badges) para hacer más prominente la idea:

  - *Civic Duty*, de plata. Votar 300 o más veces.
  - *Critic*, de bronce. Primer voto negativo.
  - *Electorate*, de oro. Votar en 600 preguntas y que al menos un 25% de los votos totales sea a preguntas.
  - *Sportsmanship*, de plata. A quien vote positivamente a 100 respuestas "competidoras", esto es, aquellas que existen en preguntas a las que tú también contestaste y tienes una puntuación de al menos 1.
  - *Suffrage*, de bronce. Votar 30 veces en un día.
  - *Supporter*, de bronce. Primer voto positivo.
  - *Vox Populi*, de bronce. Usar el máximo de 40 votos al día.

> En el momento de votar, cada ciudadano debe recordar que no está haciendo un regalo o un cumplido para complacer a alguien -o que al menos no debería hacerlo; sino que está ejecutando una de las más solemnes muestras de confianza en la sociedad.
>   — Samuel Adams

Votar es crucial para nuestra comunidad, tanto como lo es para cualquier democracia. Como moderador, o sencillamente como ciudadano del sitio: por favor, ¡ejercita tu derecho votando pronto y con frecuencia!

Comment: Me parece que está muy bien explicado, y a mí me ha venido muy bien para clarificar algunos puntos en los que tenía dudas.

Answer (score 3):

Un par de reflexiones acerca de este artículo del fundador de los *Stacks*.

Aparte de que tenemos pocas preguntas por día, parece ser que nuestras preguntas no suelen recibir, por norma, demasiados votos. Tenemos un problema de calidad además de cantidad con las preguntas? O es simplemente que tenemos el listón un poco alto para considerar que la pregunta merece un voto positivo? Si es un mala pregunta, ayudamos con comentarios o edits a hacerla mejor, más on-topic?

Ejercer correctamente nuestro privilegio de votar y discutir más en meta ayudaría a entender qué tipo de problemas tenemos con las preguntas, que es fundamental para discutir qué medidas o dirección queremos que tome esta comunidad <sup>1</sup>.

Siempre me ha dado la impresión en los stacks que las preguntas suelen recibir muchos menos votos que las respuestas. La verdad es que para empezar se valoran menos (recibimos +5 rep por *upvote* en una pregunta y el doble, +10, en una respuesta) y es fácil asumir que en el fondo el contenido importante es *la respuesta*, pues es lo que resuelve una duda y aporta conocimiento.

Me gustaría recalcar que en una comunidad todavía en Beta como somos nosotros y encima con este bajo caudal de preguntas por día es importante valorar las preguntas que recibimos a la par que somos críticos con ellas (Básicamente, preguntarnos si querríamos ver más preguntas como esa en Spanish.se y si es que no, preguntarnos cuáles son las preguntas/respuestas que queremos).

Aparte, tengamos en cuenta que para aprender es necesario a veces preguntar (y ponernos en evidencia sobre algo que desconocemos), y algunas de las preguntas que recibimos son cosas que lo mismo a nosotros nunca no se nos habría ocurrido preguntar, pero que nos llevan a aprender algo interesante y útil. Esto es algo que tenemos que valorar también.

Por último, me gustaría recalcar la cita de Samuel Adams. Es fácil que el mecanismo de votos se preste al abuso (yo no voto, pero que a mí me voten, que quiero puntos y medallas; Voto según me cae alguien de bien o mal, en lugar de votar contenido).

Votar favorece principalmente a toda la comunidad animando a mejorar la cantidad de nuestro contenido. Cierto que los *stacks* están ludificados, pero cuando ya llevas un tiempo en ellos la reputación empieza a darte un poco igual y al final escribir un buen post (pregunta o respuesta) llega a convertirse en una recompensa es sí mismo.

---

<sup>1. Posts de meta relacionados: [Intentando averiguar por qué tenemos tan pocas preguntas por día](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2633/5481) y [There is no sister site here, similar to ELL for ELU; hence some proposals](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2632/5481) dónde se sugieren algunas ideas para mejorar nuestro contenido.</sup>

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo. Por cierto: la cita de Samuel Adams no la conocía, de modo que gracias por compartirla. Me ha llamado mucho la atención.