# Nominaciones a la mejor respuesta / Best answer nominations (2018 Q1)

Tags: discusión, respuestas, promoción-de-la-comunidad, contenido

### Resultados

## Triple empate (a 5 votos) para:

- [How is “pea” translated into Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23952/5481)? de Lisa Beck
- [Acerca de la etimología de niño](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24359/5481) de Ukemi
- [¿Existe un equivalente masculino de “musa”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24463/5481) de Diego

<sub>**Nota**: se ha bloqueado esta pregunta y todas sus respuestas para que no se puedan votar y así se respeten las votaciones existentes el día que se cerró el concurso. No hagáis caso del motivo, pues no había ninguno realmente pertinente para este caso.</sub>

---

Continuando la tradición comenzada con [Nominaciones a la mejor respuesta / Best answer nominations (2017 Q4)](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2787/5481) repasemos qué preguntas y respuestas hemos tenido durante el primer trimestre de 2018.

La cuestión es fácil: revisemos entre las respuestas y contestemos en esta meta-pregunta  proponiendo cada vez una respuesta diferente. Se puede proponer más de una respuesta, publicando cada respuesta individual nominada con su propio post-respuesta a esta pregunta. Pasadas tres semanas, las tres respuestas con mejor puntuación serán las ganadoras y recibirán una recompensa en puntos. Esta vez dejamos más plazo, pero no lo ampliaremos.

Reglas:

- Indica cuáles son para ti las mejores respuestas publicadas entre el 1 de enero y el 31 de marzo de 2018.
- Cualquier respuesta es válida: pueden ser del [translation-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-golf), pueden ser de cualquier usuario, pueden contener cualquier etiqueta.
- Se puede hacer desde hoy 2 de abril hasta el domingo 22 de abril.
- Nomina respuestas, pero no olvides añadir una breve explicación de por qué te parece buena, qué has aprendido con ella, qué destacas de la respuesta, etc.
- En paralelo, ve votando las otras respuestas aportadas al concurso.
- Cuentan solamente los votos positivos, por lo que si una propuesta no te gusta, simplemente no la votes y ya está.

Estas son las respuestas publicadas en ese rango de fechas:

[Respuestas entre el 1 de enero y el 31 de marzo de 2018](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer%20created%3A2018-01..2018-03) (hay cerca de 600)

Para facilitar la búsqueda, estas son las respuestas publicadas en ese rango de fechas:

- [Preguntas del primer trimestre de 2018 con más visitas](https://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/738288/questions-with-most-views-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/01/01)
- [Preguntas del primer trimestre de 2018 con más votos](https://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/738289/questions-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/01/01)
- [Respuestas del primer trimestre de 2018  con más votos](https://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/738290/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/01/01)

Dado que esta es la segunda edición, estaremos un poco más atentos a la participación y el interés que esta pregunta despierta en el stack y añadiremos una meta-pregunta para discutir un poco más sobre esta idea (como por ejemplo, qué podemos hacer para mejorarla? Cómo mejorar o facilitar las búsquedas entre las respuestas para encontrar candidatas?)

Comment: does anyone else find it troubling that there are very good , -nay, ***Excellent*** questions in this list that only get 1 or 2 votes? Rarely do very good questions nor very good answers get surfaced on the general Stack Exchange feed on the web or mobile app because of that. I believe that f we upvoted good questions more frequently, regardless if they have been answered or not, the whole site would get better exposure on these feeds and we would all benefit from increased traffic and more interesting questions from non-native speakers who could find such questions in the aforementioned feeds

Comment: Part of the motivation of this initiative is, precisely, let people know about those hidden jewels, so they upvote great posts that they happen to miss for whichever reason. I know that is hard to navigate those lists of posts, but hopefully some questions and answers will call the attention of users and will get more upvotes. Also, related: [¿Se vota poco en este Stack?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2446/5481) and [Vota pronto y con frecuencia](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2639/5481)

Comment: desbloqueo, pues parece que ha vuelto a saltar a la casilla de destacados

Answer (score 5):

Nomino a ukemi por su gráfica respuesta a [Acerca de la etimología de niño](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/24357/acerca-de-la-etimolog%C3%ADa-de-ni%C3%B1o/24359#24359). ¡No todo van a ser enlaces al DLE!

Answer (score 4):

Nomino [¿Es posible ocultar mi género en Internet al hablar en español?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23964/5481), respondida por guifa, por la gran completitud de esta respuesta, especialmente dado lo amplio de la pregunta.

Answer (score 4):

Nomino a Diego (lo prometido es deuda) por su respuesta en [*¿Existe un equivalente masculino de “musa”?*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24463/12637), respuesta que superó con creces cualquier esperanza que pudiera tener de que realmente existiera tal equivalente.

Answer (score 4):

Nomino a Lisa Beck por su autorrespuesta en [*How is “pea” translated into Spanish?*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23952/12637), porque más que una respuesta es una tesis doctoral, y porque la respuesta con más votos del trimestre sencillamente no puede quedarse sin nominar.

Answer (score 2):

Nomino [¿Deben las definiciones del DLE ser autosuficientes?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24479/5481) de Charlie (preguntada por Blonfu) porque no solo nos hizo aprender algo, si no que entre los dos consiguieron nada menos que corregir una entrada del DLE. Qué más se podría pedir?

Answer (score 2):

Nomino a pablodf76 por todas sus respuestas :) En particular, por la que publicó en [¿Cómo evolucionó fonéticamente “jínjol” desde “zizy̆phus”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24045/1674), por aportar una visión tan coral de la lengua, mezclando etimología con fonética de una forma tan pedagógica.

Answer (score 2):

Nomino a rsanchez por su respuesta a [Word that sounds like "piso", means something like "offering"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/24390/word-that-sounds-like-piso-means-something-like-offering/24393#24393), de una pregunta que parecía vaga y que no daba muchas esperanzas de llegar a buen puerto, salió una respuesta informativa sobre un uso de "piso" que yo al menos no conocía (a pesar de conocer su acepción de "suelo").

Answer (score 2):

Nomino a Charlie y su [siesta del carnero](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/24414/tiene-alg%C3%BAn-nombre-la-siesta-que-se-hace-antes-del-almuerzo/24415#24415), algo tan cotidiando como la siesta resulta que tiene variantes según el momento del día. Cosas veredes.

Comment: I must concur with your assesment  m(n.n  )m