# Best Questions 2020 - let's build the list as we go

Tags: discusión, preguntas, respuestas

When the end of the year comes, I have a hard time remembering which questions and answers were my favorites.  But there was a doozie recently that I would like to put on the list.  So that I don't forget, come December -- let's start the list now.

Comment: This is rather subjective. Maybe you want to revisit the idea of [Nominaciones a la mejor respuesta / Best answer nominations (2018 Q1)](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2883/1674) where people would suggest and then vote which ones are the preferred among the community.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' - That's what I was trying to emulate.  However, looking back, I see that the focus was originally on the best *answer* only.  I personally think it would be worthwhile to allow people to propose an answer or a question.  If there's anything else that needs to be adjusted, to make it fit with tradition, I hope you will dive in and edit here.

Answer (score 1):

[What can be used in Spanish to convey "couch potato"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32746/9385)

It's fun to see different approaches to this.  And the question was presented in a charming way, too.