# ¿Debemos replantearnos los motivos de cierre específicos del sitio para que sean más usables?

Tags: discusión, motivos-de-cierre

<sub>Esta es la primera de una serie de propuestas que surgen a partir de la pregunta [There is no sister site here, similar to ELL for ELU; hence some proposals](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2632/1674).</sub>

▼Si tienes prisa, ve al final de la publicación ▼

---

[Comenta aparente001](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2632/1674) que debería haber un motivo de cierre que pidiera un mínimo de búsqueda a la hora de preguntar:

> There should be a built-in close reason that says, in Spanish and English, that some minimal research should be done. When one votes to close, a canned reason should appear in both languages, in a comment below the question, with the information that the commenter has voted to close. I'm not the greatest at phrasing these things -- I hope someone will draft something good for me.

Al hilo de ello me puse a revisar los motivos de cierre que tenemos actualmente. Cuando seleccionamos "close" tenemos:

- duplicate of...
- off-topic because...

  1. **Questions asking for translations are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not provide a bulk translation service.**
  2. **Questions asking for corrections in a text e.g. "are there any mistakes in this text?" are off-topic. You can ask specific sentences in separate questions that may help other users. For more information, see what you can ask [here](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).**
  3. **Questions seeking learning resources are off-topic here, but see: [Resources for learning Spanish](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2514)**
  4. This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network
  5. Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)
- unclear what you are asking
- too broad
- primarily opinion-based

Los puntos 1, 2 y 3 de "off-topic because..." son específicos para nuestro sitio ([ver los detalles](http://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/493106/off-topic-close-reasons)), con lo que estamos usando el máximo de tres razones propias que la infrastructura nos permite.

Antiguamente teníamos esta otra (no sé en lugar de cuál):

- Please look up the meaning of words or expressions in a dictionary first. If you did so and found nothing satisfactory, mention that in your question. Do give context for where you heard or saw the word.

Finalmente, esta es la que aparece cuando se cierra usando el motivo 5 o bien no hay consenso en el tipo de voto de cierre:

- This question does not appear to be about the Spanish language within the scope defined in the [help center](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Esta pregunta no parece pertenecer a este sitio de acuerdo con lo definido en [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Mirando las [estadísticas de votos de cierre](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats) (es un [privilegio a partir de 2000 puntos de reputación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)) observamos que en los últimos 90 días lo que más se ha usado es:

- (9) duplicate
- (2) too broad
- (12) off-topic - Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)
- (3) off-topic - Questions asking for corrections in a text e.g. "are there any mistakes in this text?" are off-topic. You can ask specific sentences in separate questions that may help other users. For more information, see what you can ask here.
- (3) off-topic - This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network
- (1) off-topic - Questions seeking learning resources are off-topic here, but see: Resources for learning Spanish

Vaya, que está ganando por goleada el motivo "es otro motivo" y los motivos específicos apenas se usan (la "1" no se usó, la "2" se usó 3 veces y la "3" apenas 1). No es posible desglosar los motivos de cierre en el Data explorer ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297750/209901), ojalá lo implementen algún día), por lo que no se puede hacer demasiado análisis al respecto tomando más datos que estos 90 días.

Eso sí, mirando [Cuántas preguntas se han cerrado por cada motivo](http://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/710842/how-many-posts-have-been-closed-by-each-close-reason) desde el principio de los tiempos observamos que la tendencia es la misma:

- 121 cerradas con motivo específico (ya sea motivos específicos del sitio o ad hoc para la pregunta en concreto)
- casi 100 duplicados
- menos de 30 del resto de motivos

---

**Resumiendo: parece que apenas estamos usando los motivos de cierre específicos y tendemos a usar motivos *ad hoc*. Por tanto, ¿creéis que deberíamos modificar los ya existentes para dar paso a otros más acordes con nuestras necesidades?**

Comment: @walen esto daría para otro gran debate, que está presente en todos los sitios SE. Véase por ejemplo en [es.so]: [¿Qué deberíamos hacer a las preguntas del tipo: no he intentado pero quiero respuesta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/840/83). Coincido en que debemos facilitar el aterrizaje a los usuarios nuevos, pero creo que relajar mucho el listón es contraproducente: ¿podríamos permitirnos tener un sitio graduado con 15 preguntas diarias *malas* de gente que pasaba por aquí y solo una buena? Yo prefiero 5 preguntas buenas de usuarios que vean con buenos ojos cómo funcionamos aquí.

Comment: @walen creo además que el sistema de preguntar es bastante imperfecto. Lo ideal es que fuera más claro que una pregunta cerrada está "en espera" durante un tiempo para que el autor la mejore. Creo que en Spanish.SE hemos tomado la sana costumbre de previamente mencionar todas estas cosas en los comentarios, con la intención de que el OP perfile la pregunta antes de llevarse un ristra de votos negativos como pasa en otros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se ha adoptado una solución a partir de la [propuesta de walen](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2674/1674), *golf*eándola un poco para que no superara los 400 caracteres máximos.

Por tanto, ahora tenemos estas tres:

1. <s>Questions asking for translations are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not provide a bulk translation service.</s>
2. Questions **asking for corrections in a text** e.g. "are there any mistakes in this text?" are off-topic. You can ask specific sentences in separate questions that may help other users. For more information, see what you can ask [here](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
3. <s>Questions seeking learning resources are off-topic here, but see: [Resources for learning Spanish](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2514)</s> Esta eliminada posteriormente, en diciembre de 2017, tras [Proposal: move "Resources for learning" question to the main site](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2740/1674)
4. **Questions that show no effort are off-topic**: translations & definitions easily found online; corrections (homework) posts with no clear question. Tell us what you do understand and we will help you with what you don't. **Preguntas sin esfuerzo no valen**: traducciones y definiciones fáciles de hallar; correcciones (tareas) sin pregunta clara. Di qué entiendes para ser ayudado con lo que no.

Si es necesario incluir un nuevo motivo de cierre en el futuro, eliminaríamos la 2.ª, pues puede considerarse parte de la 4.ª en según qué casos.

---

**Disclaimer**: Respuesta *posteada* en representación de @fedorqui. Él ha sido quien se ha currado este post. Yo solo copio-pego como respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

¿**Y si cambiamos el primer motivo para englobar a todas las preguntas sin esfuerzo previo**, en vez de centrarlo en traducciones?

> **Questions that show no effort are off-topic**: translations & definitions easily found online; corrections (homework) posts with no clear question. Show what you understand to be helped with what you don't. **Preguntas sin esfuerzo no valen**: traducciones y definiciones fáciles de hallar en línea; correcciones (tareas) sin una pregunta clara. Di lo que entiendes para ser ayudado con lo que no.

<strike>Desconozco el límite de caracteres</strike>Esto son exactamente 399 caracteres, que entra dentro del límite de 400. Creo que sería un motivo bastante útil. Además, **al incluir lo de las correcciones, haría redundante el segundo motivo, que quedaría libre para cualquier otro** motivo de cierre que surja en este debate y que no esté contemplado en la selección actual.

---

EDIT

Ayer me di cuenta de que, [a pesar de ser un punto específico dentro de los tipos de preguntas *off-topic*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), **no hay un motivo de cierre para preguntas que piden listas de palabras**. Y en los últimos meses ya he visto dos o tres casos.

Normalmente, **estas preguntas están hechas de forma que no entrarían en la categoría de arriba, porque muestran esfuerzo previo: proporcionan de entrada algunos de los términos buscados**. Los motivos para no aceptarlas tampoco son los mismos que para las anteriores.
Aunque ahora mismo estemos usando el "Too broad", **quizá convendría tener un motivo separado para ellas**. Sería viable si unificamos los dos primeros en uno, tal como propongo arriba.

Comment: Me gusta la idea y voto por ella. Acabo de mirarlo y el límite es de 400 caracteres, luego habría que reducir un poco. Veamos qué dice el resto de gente.

Comment: Estoy viendo que tengo [ell.se] como [elu.se] tienen razones de cierre muy curradas. Esta me gusta, propongo analizar esas para encontrar puntos de vista a los que la comunidad haya llegada a lo largo del tiempo. Y así también damos tiempo a que otra gente opine :)

Comment: Veo tu edición hablando sobre las preguntas que piden "listas de palabras". Hace unos pocos meses estuvimos debatiendo con Diego y otros acerca de este tipo de preguntas. Actualmente no se aceptan [en este sitio](/help/dont-ask), ni en general [en ninguno de la red](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/209901). Pero [en ocasiones](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/329/79601) dan pie a grandes recursos, por lo que sería un debate que valdría la pena abrir para delimitar su posible aceptación.

Comment: Demos un repaso a esta pregunta durante estos días y cambiemos el motivo de cierre. Después, abordamos este otro punto, ¿qué te parece? Yo tenía pensado en las próximas semanas ir sacando los [temas lanzados por aparente001](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2632/1674) y luego pasar a [Intentando averiguar por qué tenemos tan pocas preguntas por día](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2633/1674).

Comment: Tienes razón. Sin embargo, no creo que la llegada de septiembre ayude demasiado. La [actividad en Meta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=year) es muy baja, pero tampoco quiero que eso nos bloquee para tomar decisiones. Se me ocurre hablarlo más en el chat para que alguien más se anime a participar. De la misma manera, creo que esta concentración de personas haciendo las cosas administrativas (mirar las colas de _review_) podría intentar corregirse dejando pasar más tiempo antes de revisarlas y esperar que otros las vean.

Comment: Mil gracias por el currazo, walen. Ya lo hemos implementado y publicado [una respuesta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2701/1674) a modo de resumen.

Answer (score 1):

Las *Off-Topic* razones para cerrar, tal y como se publicaron, están mejor que antes, pero voy a proponer algunos ajustes.

> Questions that **show no effort** (Preguntas **sin esfuerzo**) are off
>   topic, e.g. simple translations that are easily found online, or
>   bare-bones homework requests. *But if you tell us what you **do
>   understand**, we will help you with what you **don't understand***.
>
> **Proofreading** questions are off topic, e.g. "are there any mistakes in this text?". *For more information, see [What you can ask
>   here](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).*
>
> Questions seeking **learning resources** are off topic, but see:
>   [Resources for learning Spanish](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2514).
>
> Belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network * *next step
>   should offer ELU, ELL and some programming SE, in addition to Meta*
>
> Other (please explain):

Comment: Interesantes propuestas, realmente me gustan. Lo que no entiendo es por qué lo propusiste justamente cuando intentábamos cerrar el debate tras tenerlo un mes abierto :P

Comment: @fedorqui - Perdón, ha habido una mudanza y varios otros trastornos entre medio.  Ayer recién me enteré que esta discusión había avanzado.

Comment: Uy, ¡una mudanza! Eso siempre es traumático jeje, ¡ánimos! Bueno, el "show no effort" es el que hemos implementado de nuevo. "Proofreading" es otra forma de decir "asking for corrections...". En "learning resources" destacas en negrita esta parte. Vaya, que es un cambio más estilístico que otra cosa, ¿no?. En cuanto a crear las rutas de migración a ELU y ELL juraría que no podemos hacerlo hasta que nos graduemos (si llega ese día). Actualmente solo se puede reportando para que lo hagan los moderadores. El texto de "I am voting to close..." no lo podemos traducir :/

Comment: @fedorqui - Creo que "proofreading" queda más claro que "asking for corrections," y además queda de acuerdo con la terminología de ELU.

Comment: Vale, lo revisamos. A ver si alguien más se pronuncia y en unos días / semanas intentamos cerrar del todo.

Comment: @fedorqui - ando con muchas distracciones de momento, así que por favor avísame explícitamente la próxima vez que haya una revisión.  Me encanta colaborar y pulir los textos.

Comment: Ejemplo de una pregunta buena que aparentemente no cuadra con la expectativa: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22454/9385

Comment: Y otro ejemplo así: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22393/9385

Comment: No entiendo qué quieres decir con _una pregunta buena que aparentemente no cuadra con la expectativa_.

Comment: @fedorqui - I cited two examples of questions that according to our site guidelines, aren't well posed, and yet I think they succeed as good questions.

Answer (score 0):

*A favor de mi propuesta original, cito algunos ejemplos de preguntas cerradas o de mala calidad:*

Pregunta 1. (cerrada, votación: -1): → [**How would the following be translated into Spanish**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17030/9385)

> > "The football costs 18 dollars"
> >
> > "Oh, that makes sense"
>
> Or just "Makes sense"

Pregunta 2. (abierta, votación: -1) → [**Exact meaning of “natural de” in a curriculum vitae?**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3810/9385)

> In a Spanish-language curriculum vitae, I came across the item
>   *Natural de:*, which I don't understand.  It is in the "Personal Data" section (*Datos personales*).

Pregunta 3. (abierta, votación: -1) → [**¿Cómo se dice "in order to soak in the culture" en español?**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20545/9385)

> As the question suggests. How would you say "in order to soak in the
>   culture".
>
> Would you say "para calar a la cultura"?

---

Lo interesante de Pregunta 3 es que a pesar de la mala calidad de la pregunta, tres personas la contestaron, y una respuesta tiene votación de 3.  En ELU, la costumbre es no contestar las preguntas de mala calidad.  A veces edito la pregunta para mejorar la calidad, si me parece interesante y la quiero contestar.

#### Proposal for a close reason:

> To be on-topic, please show what you tried already, when you were trying to figure things out on your own [link to list of resources that includes such things as Linguée], and then folks here will be happy to help you get unstuck. Para hacer una pregunta bien planteada, hay que mostrar lo que ya intentaste para resolver tu duda [enlace a los recursos como Linguée]; entonces con gusto se te brindará ayuda.

This is just walen's proposal but flipped to the positive.

Comment: Gracias por aportar ejemplos, aparente001. Nótese que la pregunta 3 al menos tiene un intento. La pregunta 1 es bastante antigua, por lo que el comportamiento de la comunidad de entonces no tiene porqué ser comparable con el actual.

Comment: @walen "There should be a built-in close reason that says, in Spanish and English, that some minimal research should be done. When one votes to close, a canned reason should appear in both languages, in a comment below the question, with the information that the commenter has voted to close. I'm not the greatest at phrasing these things -- I hope someone will draft something good for me."

Comment: @walen - Parece que no puse atención -- ¿me das un enlace, por favor?

Comment: @walen - Ah, sí, perdón.  Creo que sí coincidimos.  Un pequeño variante a tu propuesta: *To be on-topic, please show what you tried already, when you were trying to figure things out on your own [link to list of resources such as Linguée], and then folks here will be happy to help you get unstuck.  Para hacer una pregunta bien planteada, hay que mostrar lo que ya intentaste para resolver tu duda [enlace a los recursos como Linguée]; entonces los participantes aquí con gusto te ayudarán.*

Comment: @walen - Edité mi respuesta

Comment: Mil gracias por perseguir el tema, aparente. Ya lo hemos implementado y publicado [una respuesta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2701/1674) a modo resumen.