# ¿Podríamos crear la etiqueta "learner" como sinónimo de la etiqueta "principiante"?

Tags: discusión, soporte, estado-completado, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

No sé por qué, pero no puedo proponer un sinónimo para la nueva etiqueta [principante](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/principante).  Mi propuesta es

[learner](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learner)

Comment: I see that you just created the "principiante" tag based on [this thread](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2804/5481), but I think it would have been a better idea to wait longer to get more consensus from the community. Your meta question hasn't been posted for even a week, that might not be long enough given the amount of participation we usually have on meta. In fact, right now the accepted answer has a lower score than the other proposal, and there is a total of (just) four votes on two different questions +1-1 vs. +1+1) at the moment of writing this comment).

Comment: @Diego - Okay, we can wait if you like.  I only added the tag to about half a dozen questions.  (I was trying to get to the magic threshold to be able to set up the synonym, but mysteriously, I failed in this....)  I know that Meta participation is always a challenge and I wasn't terribly hopeful that waiting longer would make much of a difference, but if you want to wait another week or two I'm fine with that. // I did find people's arguments against using the existing "aprendizaje" tag persuasive.  However, personally I think that if there's a tag we DON'T want people to use, the best...

Comment: ...thing would be do REMOVE it.  When I don't want my son eating gummy bears, I make sure there aren't any gummy bears in the house.

Comment: Agreed with @Diego. The meta post did not get enough critical mass yet. We can go ahead if there are little votes but all of them are upvotes; in this specific case, there were votes in favour but also against the idea.

Comment: @fedorqui - Do you want me to remove the tag from the half-dozen questions I added it to, while we're waiting for more participation?

Comment: @aparente001 I would freeze the retagging until a decision is made.

Comment: @fedorqui - Of course.  That part was clear.  What I was asking yesterday was, do you want me to remove the tag that I added to half a dozen questions?

Comment: @aparente001 I guess I did not explain my reasoning well :) I mean to just do not retag anything yet, neither to add the tag nor to remove it from those you already added.

Comment: @fedorqui - okeydoke.

Answer (score 1):

No puedes porque no hay una etiqueta [learner](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learner).

Tenemos una etiqueta [aprendizaje](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aprendizaje) y una etiqueta [learning](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning). Al tener dos etiquetas que entendemos que se usan para lo mismo puedes proponer que una sea sinónimo de la otra, pero por supuesto ambas etiquetas deben existir.

Un sinónimo no es un "nombre adicional" si no más bien un vínculo que dice "estas dos etiquetas son la misma. Cuando busque post etiquetados por X enséñame también los de Y y vivecersa".

Comment: De hecho, los moderadores sí podemos generar un sinónimo de etiqueta pese a que no exista. Hay unos cuantos casos en la [lista de sinónimos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms), creados principalmente para cubrir este caso de cubrir el concepto en inglés y castellano.

Comment: Just to add from my perspective as a non-native speaker this discussion has taught me one thing - the Spanish word for beginner is _principante_. I think that is relevant since if after all these years I knew how to say begin (_empezar_) but not beginner then the people who are supposed to use this tag may never find it.

Answer (score 0):

I just created the the synonym, so now you have [learner](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learner) pointing to [principiante](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/principiante).

This all comes from your question [Proposal: repurpose "aprendizaje" tag](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2802/1674) in which you accepted Joze's answer that suggested using these tags. Me and others are against this, and scores of the answers suggest we are far from agreeing on this.

You added [principiante](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/principiante) to some questions and [we asked](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2813/podr%C3%ADamos-crear-la-etiqueta-learner-como-sin%C3%B3nimo-de-la-etiqueta-principiant#comment4801_2813) this to be stopped while deciding what to do. We just did not continue the discussion, so this can be a good time to resolve it :)