# Could the mods please set up a synonym for "principiante": "learner"?

Tags: discusión, soporte, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Fedorqui added the tag "principiante" to the Resources wiki thing, yay, and thank you.

As @mdewey pointed out, many learners (beginners) don't know the word "principiante."  Even some intermediate and advanced learners such as mdewey don't know the word.

Sorry to be reposting this.  I don't think I can place a bounty on my original question to draw more attention to it.

Comment: Errr note it was you who added that tag to tje question

Comment: @fedorqui - Weird.  I looked at the list of active questions, and it gave your name as having made an edit on the page 20 something hours before.  I couldn't find any March edits.  Then, and I don't remember how, but it seems I made a big leap somewhere in there, and concluded that you had added the tag. // Has enough time gone by?  Is it not reasonable to have an English tag synonym for *principiante*?  Here's a good reason to have it: beginners need some leeway, and they need a certain simplified style of explanation.  For example, if a beginner is struggling

Comment: with their subject or object pronouns, we shouldn't use any past tense verbs (and certainly not any subjunctive) in the answer.

Comment: Check revision 12 in the [Revisions page](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/23617/revisions) :) Regarding the use of this tag, I am against and Diego also, as indicated in the discussion of [Proposal: repurpose “aprendizaje” tag](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2802/1674): I think it is a meta tag that does not add any value and won't be easy to maintain. Better add some wiki or some canonical question like [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/3462) in [ell.se].

Comment: @fedorqui - The canonical post idea is quite intriguing and it's got my mind jumping with ideas. // While it's interesting to know what two of our four moderators think, and in this case that opinion seems to match the prevailing consensus, I think we should recognize the community's role in addition to the moderators'. // Aside from the canonical post, I personally still think a *beginner* tag would be helpful.  It would distinguish the ELL-type questions.  But I'm in the minority so maybe it's time to remove the "principiante" tags I tentatively assigned?

Comment: @fedorqui - So I guess I'll dig in and start removing the "principiante" tags?  Note, as I've been working more with tags I've been coming around to your point of view, but regardless, the decision was not to have this tag, and as far as I can tell you haven't removed them so shall I go ahead?

Comment: Since no new ideas have come, yes, we can assume now that [tag:principiante] was not necessary and we should remove it from the questions. Thanks for remembering this issue.