# Una vez al año no hace daño: propuesta para permitir preguntas off-topic

Tags: discusión, off-topic

Siguiendo la popular filosofía de "una vez al año no hace daño", llevo un tiempo dándole vueltas a la posibilidad de permitir, durante un día concreto del año, hacer preguntas en el sitio que normalmente se considerarían *off-topic*.

Estoy seguro de que muchos de nosotros (yo incluido) hemos pensando alguna vez en preguntar algo relacionado con el idioma, y no hemos podido hacerlo porque contravenía las normas del sitio: era una pregunta de opinión, o una en la que todas las respuestas pueden ser válidas.

¿Qué tal si elegimos, pues, un día al año en el que se permitan este tipo de preguntas? Siempre y cuando tengan como tema central el idioma español (esto siempre) y se hagan con respeto y, por qué no, sentido del humor, y aporten un toque de distensión a la seriedad habitual con la que tratamos las preguntas y sus respuestas.

Por mi parte, propongo usar el Día de los Inocentes, el 28 de diciembre (celebrado en España y algunos lugares de Hispanoamérica), aunque también podríamos usar el más internacional April's Fool: el 1 de abril, que no lo celebramos como tal pero ya casi todo el mundo lo conoce.

Si os parece, proponed vuestras fechas alternativas. O si no os parece, pues votad que no.

---

EDIT: Normas para mitigar posibles efectos secundarios sobre el sitio:

- Solo se podrán hacer preguntas que sean sobre el idioma español.
- Toda pregunta que entre en esta categoría deberá ser marcada como CW para no generar reputación.
- Las preguntas deberán ir etiquetadas como [día-de-los-inocentes](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d%c3%ada-de-los-inocentes) o similar, según el día elegido finalmente.
- También se pueden iniciar con un mensaje como el que sigue:

  > Pregunta *offtopic* realizada con motivo del Día de los Inocentes. Consulta las normas en [enlace aquí].

Comment: Voto por el 28 de diciembre. Primero porque queda más cerca pero también porque encaja mejor con el sitio

Comment: @blonfu puedes ponerlo como respuesta (algo así como "Sí, el 28 de diciembre") y luego añadir tus explicaciones, para que los demás puedan votar tu respuesta si están de acuerdo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Disculpad que no me pronunciara hasta la fecha)

#### No me gusta la idea...

Las publicaciones en este sitio surgen con vocación atemporal. Además del problema conceptual de permitir preguntas *off-topic*, esta atemporalidad (no importa cuándo se publicó, sino qué) provocaría que el mensaje que se enviara a los futuros usuarios fuera equívoco: hoy puedo publicar esto, ¿pero mañana no? Y si es una pregunta *off-topic* ya publicada, ¿por qué no acepta respuestas la semana que viene?
Las fronteras del *off-topic* se verían desbordadas y desdibujadas (perdón por la metáfora si suena exagerada), con lo que ya no dispondríamos de elementos claros para definir el *on-topic* en el futuro.

#### ... pero puede ser un buen momento para aumentar los límites del *off-topic*

Tal y como ha comentado Diego en sus dos respuestas, creo más práctico definir qué tipo de preguntas nos gustaría preguntar pero ahora no podemos plantear. Probablemente nos demos cuenta de que redefiniendo el *on-topic* podríamos abrazar algún extremo que ahora mismo no.

Por ejemplo me fijé hace poco que en [Mathematics.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com) tienen preguntas de petición de referencias o libros:

- [Non-textbook Math book recommendation to read to my kids](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2516970/79601) (etiquetas [soft-question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question) y [book-recommendation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation))
- [Best Algebraic Topology book/Alternative to Allen Hatcher free book?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/84409/79601) (etiquetas [reference-request](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) y [book-recommendation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation))

Que podrían relacionarse con la canónica [Resources for learning Spanish](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2514/1674) que últimamente hemos planteado mover al sitio principal para así ejercer de atractora de duplicados.

O yo en su momentó pregunté aquí [¿Puede escindirse el castellano en el futuro?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13376/1674), que se me cerró en su momento (no lo discuto) pero que tiene un primo hermano en la fantástica [¿Podría un hispanohablante actual entenderse bien con uno del pasado?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17145/1674), que sí se consideró on-topic.

En definitiva, creo que somos una comunidad madura, con unos cuantos miembros (vosotros, los que estáis leyendo esto) con unas ganas enormes de hacerla mejor y que, por tanto, estamos en un momento idóneo para reabrir estos límites. Pero creo también importante redifinirlos más que saltárnoslos un día para volver al "aburrimiento de las reglas" del día después.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo.

Answer (score 2):

A mi la idea, aunque original, no me parece productiva para el sitio.

Cierto es que la base de los stacks es que es la comunidad quien modera el sitio en diversos niveles. Sin embargo, estamos proponiendo ir contra nuestras mismas reglas. En Meta hemos discutido diversas cosas como dónde ponemos los límites para lo off-topic, si permitimos cierto tipo de preguntas o hasta dónde podemos forzar un poco las reglas (el [translation-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-golf), que es bastante exitoso es un buen ejemplo de esto). Pero en este caso, estamos hablando de ignorar por completo nuestras propias reglas.

Esos límites no se hacen cumplir de manera matemática, si no que casi pregunta por pregunta la comunidad decide, por lo que (aunque solo sea un día al año y con un tag especial y lo que sea) permitir preguntas que no se adhieren a las reglas generales puede causar confusión y pervertir la temática del sitio.

Yo entiendo (y comparto) ese instinto de querer preguntar algo no relacionado con la temática del stack pero querer preguntarlo en el stack. Al fin y al cabo, cuando empiezas a conocer a los otros usuarios les coges afecto y confías más en su criterio, y querrías pedir consejo sobre cosas que puede que vayan a otro stack o que ni siquera pertenezan a la familia de stacks de stackExchange (como usar este stack como una versión de los de Personal Finance & Money o Home Imporvement pero en español).

Desafortunadamente, creo que nos estaríamos disparando a nosotros mismos en el pie. Esas preguntas pueden quedar ahí *per secula seculorum* y ser un mal ejemplo para otra gente que plantea preguntas off-topic (como por ejemplo preguntas que pertenecen a otro stack) y que cerramos o migramos.

Creo que en el fondo, aunque este sitio parezca que vaya a estar en perpetua beta (lo que no creo que sea malo del todo), deberíamos sentirnos afortunados de tener toda esta infraestructura a nuestro servicio. Desgraciadamente, no creo que podamos forzar las reglas para permitir, si quiera de forma esporádica, romper nuestras propias reglas (entiendo que esas preguntas no pertenecen ni a Spanish.se ni a otro stack. Lo mismo tienen que ir a Reddit o Quora u otro sitio).

Una cosa es decidir qué es o no on-topic y otra ignorar las reglas por completo.

Creo que lo suyo sería usar, si queremos usar este stack o cntactar con los usuarios del mismo, los medios que disponemos aquí, como La Tertulia.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Añado otra respuesta, en base a los *edits* de la pregunta, comentarios y respuestas ya aportadas.</sub>

Básicamente lo que estamos proponiendo es ir en contra de nuestras propias normas (consensuadas) y permitir un "día de amnistía". Podemos proponer cualquier fecha, pero eso es realmente lo que es.

No olvidemos que esta plataforma se ha intentado optimizar para formatos de *"Q&A"* (preguntas y respuestas) haciendo "flotar" el contenido de calidad a base de votos y manteniendo la temática del sitio *on topic* según las reglas consensuadas en meta.

Esto también implica que, en cualquier pregunta (o post) un usuario puede votar algo como *off-topic* u *on-topic* (o como *not an answer*). Se puede equivocar o no pero (a menos que sea moderador, cuyos votos son vinculantes), es la comunidad la que decide en última instancia, y no un único individuo. No es la filosofía de este sitio que la voluntad de una única persona decida si algo se cierra, borra, etc.

Lo de "una vez al año no hace daño" o "que se rompen las reglas de forma excepcional" me convencería si no fuera porque:

- Rompemos nuestras propias reglas de forma flagrante.
- Lo de que lo "hacemos solo por esta vez" tiene el peligro de repetirse y en mayor proporción.
- El contenido realmente queda para siempre (con lo cual hemos añadido una serie de preguntas que bajo otras circunstancias habríamos considerado *off topic* y/o de baja calidad.

Entiendo que estas preguntas llevarían su "advertencia", como se propone en la pregunta, con su tag [día-de-amnistía](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d%c3%ada-de-amnist%c3%ada) y un enlace a esta discusión meta], pero pese a ello ahí quedarían en el sitio. Entiendo que se hacen *community wiki*, pero, deben dejarse abiertas de forma permanente? Deben dejarse abiertas más allá de este día de amnistía?

Si no es así, hay gente que puede estar en desventaja respecto a poder publicar (entiendo que si el día de amnistía es el 28 de diciembre el tiempo se mide en UTC, por lo que hay gente de ciertas franjas horarias que lo puede tener un poco más difícil para publicar.

Si las preguntas se dejan abiertas más allá del día de amnistía entonces estamos introduciendo contenido que bajo otras circunstancias no querríamos.

Me hago eco del comentario de Walen

> El espíritu de la propuesta me gusta, pero creo que falla el *scope*... Quizá aceptar cualquier cosa off-topic es pasarse, pero permitir al menos preguntas de opinión estaría bien.

Con la amnistía, es posible que encontremos alguna pregunta interesante aunque off-topic, pero también preguntas de baja calidad (cosas que se pueden responder fácilmente con un diccionario o que no muestren esfuerzo previo) ¿Qué pasaría con preguntas mal redactadas que llevan el tag [día-de-amnistía](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d%c3%ada-de-amnist%c3%ada)? ¿O con simples peticiones de traducir o corregir un texto? ¿Supongo que esas se ignoran y después del día de amnistía se cierran como el resto de los días?

Uno de los problemas que veo es, como dicen walen, que no querríamos tampoco cualquier cosa y si tenemos que decidir qué queremos y qué no, entonces estamos haciendo otra discusión sobre lo on-topic y lo off-topic, lo que da la sensación de que (seguramente no pase, debido a la tendencia de preguntas que tenemos en el sitio pero) el tiro pueda salir por la culata.

No me pondría tampoco tan quisquilloso por que el contenido se quedase de forma permanente si no fuera porque se podría hacer mal uso de esos tags, y con un retag anónimo, marcar preguntas que no proceden con el tag o retirárselo a otras.

De nuevo, haciendo eco del comentario de walen, en el pasado hemos intentado averiguar cómo abordar preguntas de tipo lista o preguntas tipo "en qué países estos sucede o se dice así" o preguntas con respuestas tipo "en mi país se dice así/ en este otro es distinto".

Ahí veo una discusión que puede beneficiar al sitio, forzando las reglas quizá un poco, pero sin saltárselas de forma descarada y vergonzosa (pues son nuestras propias normas). Quizá podemos explorar de otra manera preguntas de opinión o similares, pero no veo bien permitir lo que hemos acordado ya como off-topic.

En [Give each site a parallel site for polling, recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57383/356575) se propone la posibilidad de añadir secciones a los sitios para añadir contenido subjetivo, recomendaciones, encuestas y similar, que puede aportar algo de luz acerca de qué hacer con contenido "interesante, relacionado con la temática del stack, pero descaradamente off-topic". El propio Jeff Atwood sugiere que [eso pertenece a otro sitio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75035/356575), pero no es apropiado para los stack con formato Q&A.

Comment: La "amnistía" es para esas preguntas, que recibirían un trato especial, no para sus OPs. Cierto que las reglas no están escritas en piedra, pero como digo esto no se trata de revisar los límites ni de estudiar otros enfoques (a lo que estoy abierto), si no de dejarlas pasar directamente. Para nuevos usuarios podría ser confuso y parecer hipócrita ("cerráis mi pregunta cuando vosotros hicisteis en su momento esta otra similar?") Y lo del "homework" es relevante, pues habría de definir el "ontopic" dentro del "offtopic" de las preguntas de ese día, y veo muy difícil ser coherente en eso.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo veo una iniciativa interesante.

Es cierto que las preguntas quedan para siempre en el sitio y podría confundir a la gente que haya algunas preguntas fuera de las normas habituales del sitio, sin embargo solo es un día y se podrían identificar de alguna forma las preguntas para que se vea que son especiales -¿Con una etiqueta en los títulos quizá?- y empezar su redacción advirtiendo que es una pregunta *offtopic* permitida solo un día en concreto.

Podría haber diferentes formas de dejar claro que se rompen las reglas de forma excepcional.

Por poner una analogía supongamos una familia que tiene la norma de no comer dulces. Si el día del cumpleaños del hijo se permite romper esa regla y comen una tarta ¿Se destruirá la relación familiar por ello? Yo creo que no y seguramente sea bueno relajar las normas de vez en cuando.

*La ley está para cumplirla* pero *las reglas están para romperlas*. Voto a favor de la propuesta de @Charlie y por el día 28 de diciembre para realizarla.

> **NOTA**
>
> Como parece que hay alguna duda sobre esto yo hablo de preguntas  que están relacionadas con la temática del sitio pero que las normas no permiten. Es lo que propone @Charlie en el segundo párrafo de su propuesta:
>
> *«Estoy seguro de que muchos de nosotros (yo incluido) hemos pensando alguna vez en preguntar algo relacionado con el idioma, y no hemos podido hacerlo porque contravenía las normas del sitio: era una pregunta de opinión, o una en la que todas las respuestas pueden ser válidas.»*

Answer (score 1):

Lo he dado a entender en un par de comentarios, pero creo que procede reflejarlo en una respuesta.

La iniciativa me parece buena, siempre que se refiera a permitir preguntas que son "*off-topic* técnico"; es decir, que aun estando relacionadas con el idioma español, se consideran *off-topic* por estar así definido en las normas del sitio o de SE:

- Preguntas subjetivas: la palabra más graciosa, la frase más bonita, la construcción más complicada.
- Preguntas de opinión: sobre normas, sobre cambios, sobre la RAE, sobre reformas, sobre definiciones...
- Preguntas de literatura hispánica, quizá...
- Preguntas sobre otros idiomas y dialectos usados en zonas de habla hispana: mapuche, vasco, catalán, gallego... O incluso tagalo, sefardí y similares.

Preguntas serias sobre esos temas, me parece que pueden aportar cosas interesantes. Se podría fijar un día para hacerlas, dar algunas semanas de margen para las respuestas, y después cerrarlas.

No vería bien en cambio que se aprovechase ese día para preguntar cosas sobre economía, política, cultura popular y otros temas que no tengan nada que ver con el idioma español, o simplemente paridas del tipo *100tifiko jajaja saludos*, o en general preguntas que no estén orientadas a generar un debate civilizado y/o a recopilar información curiosa o interesante.

**NOTA** - Sobre la fecha: tras pensarlo un poco, precisamente por lo dicho arriba de que el objetivo no es aceptar preguntas chorras ni troleos, creo que **la fecha del 28-dic no es la adecuada**. Por ser un día en el que es tradición hacer bromas, **mandaría un mensaje erróneo a los usuarios de que lo que se espera son "preguntas de broma"**.
En el caso de que la iniciativa salga adelante, opino que sería mejor buscar otra fecha sin esa connotación.

Comment: Ciertamente, no queda claro en el texto de la pregunta, pero sí, me refería a preguntas como las que sugieres, que no abandonen la esencia de preguntar cosas del idioma español. Y por cierto: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15863/12637

Comment: La intención de @Charlie queda clara en esta frase: _hemos pensando alguna vez en preguntar algo relacionado con el idioma, y no hemos podido hacerlo porque contravenía las normas del sitio_ . A mi tampoco me parece bien tratar temas que nada tengan que ver con el sitio, para eso se puede usar el chat.

Comment: Lo de cambiar de fecha me parece bien, me ha convencido tu argumento.