# "Una vez al año" revisited

Tags: discusión, off-topic

Soon it'll be two years ago that Charlie made this proposal: [Una vez al año no hace daño: propuesta para permitir preguntas off-topic](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2725)

Back then, and judging by the comments and answers posted, the proposal was supported by at least 3 active, high-rep users and rejected by at least 3 of the 4 then-current mods.

Nowadays, most of then-current mods have stepped down, and some are not even active users anymore. On the other hand, Charlie is now a mod himself, and most if not all of the users that showed their support are still active.

**I am not making the same proposal again** (not yet ). However, I am curious about whether our perception of this issue has changed over time, and how.

Comment: I am still against it :) I cannot see how posting "off topic" on purpose can be beneficial to the site. In any case, as I mentioned in my answer (which was accepted), it is a matter of changing the scope of the site, so such questions are welcomed all year long.

Comment: I understand the reasons why the question was ultimately downvoted and I still support the accepted answer by @fedorqui. But we can still study how to broaden the limits of the site. Maybe we can accept opinion-based questions about the Spanish language as long as both the question and the answers are CW, as we do with the translation-golf questions.

Comment: (by the way, in order to count people supporting or not: my answer there got +4 back then, it's been today that it got its first -1 - no other post there was voted today)

Comment: Not sure how relevant this is but I understand that the Judaism site allows humorous posts during Purim with strict rules on format and then they are locked when Purim ends. Their policy is here https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated Note I am not on that site, not a follower of any religion but I noticed it by chance somehow.

Comment: Qué tal si en los cuatro días de Thanksgiving (jueves - domingo)?

Comment: @walen - Ah, perdón.  Pues a mí me parece que valdría la pena probar la idea.  Un poco de diversión nos quedaría bien en estos tiempos.

Comment: @walen - No sé, ha pasado algo de tiempo, y ha habido much tristeza y alboroto en estas semanas.  Por lo menos a mi me hace falta un poco de diversión.

Comment: @mdewey there's precedent! :-D

Comment: Yo sigo pensando igual así que me remito a la respuesta que di en su día: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2727/14069