# Propuesta de nuevo tipo de preguntas: concursos de popularidad

Tags: discusión, preguntas, ámbito

Ya en su día cogí del sitio de [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) la idea del Translation Golf, juego que a día de hoy lleva ya 50 ediciones, y no quería perder la ocasión de coger otra de las ideas que se gestaron allí para proner aquí otro tipo de preguntas: **los concursos de popularidad**.

Los concursos de popularidad son algo sencillo: se plantea una pregunta que puede generar varias respuestas igualmente válidas, y se marca como respuesta válida aquella que más votos ha conseguido generar en un determinado espacio de tiempo.

Dicho así suena muy genérico, y es por eso que me gustaría que esta pregunta resolviera varias cuestiones en realidad:

1. ¿Veis factible permitir en el sitio este tipo de preguntas en los que la mejor respuesta queda como una elección subjetiva? En realidad se podría plantear como cualquier otra pregunta: ganaría la respuesta que mejor ayude al OP, a su propio criterio.
2. En caso afirmativo, ¿qué clases de preguntas concretas creéis que podrían encajar aquí? Lo digo para acotar el ámbito de este tipo de preguntas y que no sea tan genérico, porque si no corremos el riesgo de que alguien nos pida una traducción de un texto (cosa que ahora mismo no está permitida) y lo ponga como un concurso de popularidad.
3. Si no os convence la idea, pero creéis que se puede plantear de otra forma, ¿qué se os ocurre? ¿Qué se os pasa por la cabeza?

**La idea de la que parte esto** es que como traductor aficionado a veces me he encontrado cosas en traducciones que son muy complicadas de mantener, como los juegos de palabras. Muchas veces me ha ayudado comentar los juegos de palabras con otras personas, a las que se les ocurrían cosas que a mí no y al final las traducciones quedaban mucho mejor. Podría ser de mucha utilidad para traductores si se permitiera esta pequeña excepción, serían preguntas a medio camino entre la traducción y la solicitud de término. O simplemente podríamos plantearlas nosotros como juego si vemos algún caso de juego de palabras que creamos que se podría haber hecho mejor.

Lo de plantearlo como concursos de popularidad es porque la respuesta dependería más del ingenio que del conocimiento, y al poder haber respuestas igualmente ingeniosas ganaría la más votada (o la que más le convenga al OP a su criterio, si se decide así). Además, también quería ver si hay algún otro tipo de pregunta aparte de la traducción de juegos de palabras que pudiera encajar en este ámbito. Así a bote pronto se me ocurre la traducción de alguna pequeña cantidad de versos en los que estos hayan de rimar, como ya nos ha ocurrido alguna vez con los Translation Golf bonificados por rima, en los que hemos tenido que tirar muchas veces de ingenio. Aquí habría que limitar la cantidad de versos a traducir, por supuesto.

Si al final solo se aceptan las preguntas sobre traducciones de juegos de palabras, y si creéis que estas ya están permitidas dentro de la etiqueta [traducción](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traducci%c3%b3n) (al igual que se busca la mejor forma de traducir cualquier término o expresión extranjera), especificadlo así en vuestra respuesta. Tampoco estoy planteando este tipo de preguntas como algo a limitar, como el Translation Golf, a una vez por semana, ni que deba ser por turnos, a fin de cuentas no creo que salgan tantas preguntas de este tipo. Es más bien por ver cómo ampliar un poquito más los límites del sitio.

Hale, planteado queda. Espero vuestras opiniones. :-)

---

As an example: In The Lego Movie 2 there is a character named Watevra Wa'Nabi, a parody on "whatever wannabe" but made to resemble a real name. In Spanish the name was translated to Soyloque Quiera, which does not resemble any real Spanish name. Could you propose a different translation that keeps the word pun and also resembles a real Spanish name? This would certainly not help anyone with their Spanish knowledge, but it might be a fun question to answer.

Comment: Francamente no entendí la idea del todo.  Quizás entenderé mejor con un ejemplo.

Comment: @aparente001 example: in _The Lego Movie 2_ there is a character named Watevra Wa'Nabi, a parody on "whatever wannabe" but made to resemble a real name. In Spanish the name was translated to Soyloque Quiera, which does not resemble to any Spanish real name. Could you propose a different translation that keeps the word pun and also resembles a Spanish real name? This would certainly not help anyone with their Spanish knowledge, but it would a fun question to answer, maybe.

Answer (score 2):

Mi respuesta es un **sí condicional** y con un pero.

Inicialmente iba a votar no, ya que no me gusta permitir situaciones en las que se admiten preguntas que de otra manera serían off-topic (tipo [Una vez al año no hace daño: propuesta para permitir preguntas off-top](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2725/5481)).

Me parece que este tipo de preguntas están bien para el usuario experimentado, que ya domina el stack (casi hasta se aburre debido a la escasez de preguntas) y quiere más, pero por otro lado puede ser confuso para otros usuarios nuevos y puede dar a situaciones tipo "por qué se cierra mi pregunta por off-topic si no es tan disitnta a esta otra de aquí".

Viendo el ejemplo-experimento propuesto en [¿Cómo traducir el nombre “Queen Watevra Wa'Nabi” manteniendo el juego de palabras?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32166/5481) creo que **este tipo de preguntas podrían ser posibles siempre que las tratásemos como un juego**, tipo translation-golf.

Incluso en el translation golf es necesario proponer una respuesta, para que la pregunta no sea "off-topic" (al pedir una traducción sin haber hecho antes un esfuerzo por traducir). Creo que de manera similar, para estas preguntas debería ser necesario:

- que se añadiese la etiqueta de "juego" a la pregunta
- que pregunta y respuestas fuesen community wiki
- que no hubiese más de una por semana

Vamos, como en el translation golf, y casi me dan ganas de proponer que quien "gane" el concurso de popularidad debería tener el privilegio de proponer el siguiente, igual que se hace en le translation-golf.

Cómo compaginar este juego con el translation-golf, ya es otra cuestión (permitimos dos juegos en paralelo por semana o solo uno?).

Ahora viene mi "pega" (o pero) y reflexión: no sé hasta qué punto [¿Cómo traducir el nombre “Queen Watevra Wa'Nabi” manteniendo el juego de palabras?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32166/5481) es un buen ejemplo de un concurso de popularidad.

Me explico, la mayoría de preguntas de SE son un concurso de popularidad, aunque sea tan básico como "A ver quién le explica mejor esto al OP". Muchas preguntas, incluso aquellas que parecen tener "respuesta única" (tipo "la RAE dice que esto es así - pongo referencia") se prestan a tener múltiples respuestas que lo explican distinto o con distintos ejemplos, y salvo que las respuestas sean muy muy similares se admiten como distintas, y el "concurso de popularidad" es que una respuesta está más trabajada (mejor explicada, mejores ejemplos, enlaces, etc.)

La primera vez que leí lo de los concurso de popularidad pensé en algo tipo "Qué suena mejor al oído 'fuéramos' o 'fuésemos'", que por supuesto es completamente subjetivo. En [¿Cómo traducir el nombre “Queen Watevra Wa'Nabi” manteniendo el juego de palabras?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32166/5481) hay cierto nivel de subjetividad, pero creo que no mucho más del que hay en preguntas tipo "cuál es la mejor traducción para este término" y similares.

Hay una diferencia entre "se admiten múltiples respuestas, cuál es la mejor de ellas es completamente subjetivo" y "se admiten múltiples respuestas, algunas pueden ser mejores que otras en base a ciertos criterios", y creo que el ejemplo propuesto es más un caso de lo segundo que de lo primero.

Comment: Las cosas que comentas ya se me habían ocurrido. La primera es que si se piensa fríamente cualquier pregunta es un concurso de popularidad. La segunda es que podríamos restringir su publicación con las reglas de juego de TG, pero ¿y si un traductor quiere plantear una cuestión similar para una situación real? No podemos decirle que primero tiene que ganar otra edición, y tampoco creo que estas preguntas sean de ocurrencia fácil. Por eso no quise plantear estas preguntas como juegos.

Answer (score 1):

Me gusta la idea. En principio ese tipo de preguntas serían perfectamente *ontopic*, el tema es cómo se van a plantear para darle ese toque lúdico y que no sea una pregunta más. Respondiendo a tus preguntas:

1. No veo ningún problema con eso, no es muy diferente de cualquier otra pregunta.
2. Se puede poner una traducción literal (como hacemos en los [translation-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-golf)) y especificar que lo que buscamos es una traducción que mantenga el juego de palabras o unas premisas definidas como rima, métrica o cierta sonoridad.
3. Nada que decir aquí.

La duda para mi es cómo se haría, ¿que sea una pregunta *wiki* como los juegos de TG o se dejan normal y que sumen reputación? ¿Llevarían la etiqueta [juegos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/juegos) o se identificarían de otra forma?

A ver si se pasa la gente por aquí a discutir el tema y lo descartamos o lo ponemos en marcha.